# rails: define a new method while also calling another method in the same controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails project here. In the controller, I have one method defined 
`single_output`, and if the url is like `/single_output/1`, it will give me the info of `person_id=1` and then I want to add another method `group_output` in the same controller, but will need to call `single_output`. Basically what I want it do is if url is like `/group_output/1`, it will give me the info of `group_id=1` which includes some `person_id` and these `person_id` will give me all their info.

My solution is this:

Controller:

```
def single_output
    person_id = param[:person.id]
    result = Person.where(:person_id => person_id)
end

def group_output
    group_id = params[:group_id]
    person_ids = Group.where(:group_id => group_id)
    person_ids.each do |person_id|
        output = get '/single_output/' + person_id
    end
end
```

Route:

```
match "School/single_output/:person_id(.:format)" => "School#single_output"
match "School/group_output/:group_id(.:format)" => "School#group_output"
```

But seems like the `get` method is not a good way to do this.

Or I come up with another idea:

```
redirect_to '/single_output/' + person_id
```

But it shows `Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular way to do this is to use another method.

```
def single_output
    get_person(params[:person_id])
end

def group_output
    group_id = params[:group_id]
    person_ids = Group.where(:group_id => group_id)
    person_ids.each do |person_id|
        output = get_person(person_id)
    end
end

private

def get_person(id)
  Person.where(person_id: id)
end
```

But your code is unusual... I would expect `person_ids` in the `group_output` would be an array of `Group` objects.  Does a Group object `has_many` people?  And do you need an array or just the first matching Group object?  In which case you would just need to do...

```
def single_output
    get_person(params[:person_id])
end

def group_output
    @group = Group.find_by(group_id: params[:group_id])
end

private

def get_person(id)
  Person.find_by(person_id: id)
end
```

And in your output view you would just iterate through `@group.people` which would be all people who belong to the group.

And finally, the rails convention is that a record id is just called `id` not `record_id` so in a standard rails app I'd expect it to be `@group = Group.find_by(id: params[:group_id])` or even `@group = Group.find(params[:group_id])` although this version will raise an exception if the group record is not found.